# Prisma - How to use count as a where condition with relation

Tags: prisma, prisma2

I use `nestjs` and `postgresql` with `prisma`. I have 2 tables in relation, I want to create a where clause in order to fetch the records if count of the records in the second table is less than -let's say- 3. More details;

Here is my schema

```
model User {
  id                      String            @id
  someOtherFields         String
  outgoingPlayMateRequest PlayMateRequest[] @relation("userId")
  incomingPlayMateRequest PlayMateRequest[] @relation("targetId")
}

model PlayMateRequest {
  id               Int      @id
  requestingUser   User     @relation(name: "userId", fields: [requestingUserId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  targetUser       User     @relation(name: "targetId", fields: [targetUserId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  requestingUserId String
  targetUserId     String
  someOtherFields  String
  response         String   //accept-reject-block
}
```

and here is my code with where clause (I am simplfying it by removing unrelevant parts)

```
const userId = 'testUser';
return await this.prismaService.user.findMany({
    where: {
      NOT: {
        id: userId //don't fetch user him/herself
      },
      lang: 'EN',
    }
  });
```

**The condition I want to add here** in english is;

> Don't select users with incomingPlayMateRequest relation, if there are
> 3 records in PlayMateRequest table with `response = reject` AND
> `requestingUser = userId`

But I couldn't find anyway to use `count` as a condition in where. As I see I can only get the relations count. How can I do this with `prisma`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no direct way to do a condition like this in Prisma, but here is a workaround you could use:

1. Do a `groupBy` query for the filter condition.
2. Use a `map` to create array of `User.id` fields of all the user ids that match the filter condition.
3. Do the normal `findMany` query, but add an extra `notIn` condition with the array of filtered user ids.

Here is what the whole thing would look like:

```js
const userId = 'testUser';

// step 1
const dataForFilter = await prisma.playMateRequest.groupBy({
    by: ['targetUserId'],
    where: {
        response: "reject",
        requestingUserId: userId
    },
    having: {
        targetUserId: {
            _count: {
                equals: 3  
            }
        }
    }
})

// step 2
let exclude_users = [userId]
exclude_users = exclude_users.concat(dataForFilter.map(item => item.targetUserId))

let result = await prisma.playMateRequest.user.findMany({
    where: {
        id: {
        notIn: exclude_users
        },
        lang: "en"
    }
    });
```

I might have misinterpreted the exact details of the query you want to achieve but I think this should give you the query structure in general. Tweak the `groupBy` query as necessary to match your exact condition.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. I was hoping there would be a direct way but this is a solution. Thanks for the help @Tasin Ishmam

Comment: Welcome, happy to help!